# How to properly duplicate a working Laravel 4 project

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have the latest Laravel 4 beta 5 build from Laravel's [github repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop).

I have built a simple web API and it is working fine. I wanted to duplicate the project to another folder and continue working on it from the copy. However, when I try that, I get the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Driver [native] not supported.

/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy/bootstrap/compiled.php
    Line 10908: throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Driver [{$driver}] not supported.");
```

Here is what I did in order to copy the project:

```
[/Users/tolga/Sites] $ cp -R l4api l4api-copy
[/Users/tolga/Sites] $ chmod -R 755 l4api-copy
```

It didn't work, so I've tried:

```
[/Users/tolga/Sites] $ chmod -R 777 l4api-copy/app/storage
```

Still no good, tried to run composer dump-autoload:

```
[/Users/tolga/Sites] $ cd l4api-copy
[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $ composer.phar dump-autoload
 Generating autoload files

[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $
```

Same error. I have also tried to remove the `app/storage` folder and re-create it.

```
[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $ rm -Rf app/storage
[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $ mkdir app/storage
[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $ chmod -R 777 app/storage/
```

Here is a brand-new error:

```
ErrorException

Warning: file_put_contents(/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy/bootstrap/../app/storage/meta/services.json):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
    /Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy/bootstrap/compiled.php line 5507

        Line 5507: return file_put_contents($path, $contents);
```

I have also run `composer.phar dump-autoload` command again, after emptying the `app/storage` folder.

And finally, I have also tried `composer.phar install`:

```
[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $ composer.phar install
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Installing dependencies from lock file
 Nothing to install or update
 Generating autoload files

[/Users/tolga/Sites/l4api-copy] $
```

None of the above helped. What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to duplicate a working project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a [recent commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/d9c559ba7f3e92d0623df0cd30f8f8e5ae7a7aff) to the **laravel/laravel** repository a new session driver, `native`, has been introduced. From the looks of your errors you should update your application skeleton (the cloned develop branch of laravel/laravel), delete your `bootstrap/compiled.php` file and re-run `composer update` to pull in the latest framework changes.

In terms of copying the project you should copy over everything *except* the `vendor` directory then run `composer install` in the new location. You could copy the `vendor` directory but it's better to run a clean install and let composer dump a new autoload.

I've also seen Taylor mention a cleanup of your `app/storage/sessions` directory. Delete all the files in there.

Comment: Wow, that commit was 3 hours ago. Before copying I've fetched and merged in my working app, and it still works. But I will check if the changes are applied. Thank you.

Comment: I've first run `composer update` in my working app, and it broke with the same error (Driver [native]...). Then as per your suggestion, I've deleted `bootstrap/compiled.php` and re-run composer. And now it works. Duplicating it also works. Thank you. I guess fetching and merging from the git does not properly update it.

Comment: Just for information; for copying the project, I've copied everything, set the permissions, and deleted `app/storage/sessions` directory. Everything worked fine.

Comment: Yep, the `bootstrap/compiled.php` file is great when you deploy. For local development I'd avoid using it as it can cause some troubles. There was a patch that deleted the file before a `composer update` but it was removed. Just be wary of it unless you're deploying an application in which case you should remove it before you run `composer updated`.