# Laravel 4: 404 error after copying project from Ubuntu to Windows 8

Tags: php, windows, laravel-4, wamp

I tried copying a working Laravel 4 project from Ubuntu to Windows running WAMP (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053297/how-to-properly-duplicate-a-working-laravel-4-project) as a guide), but I get a 404 error on every route.

The odd thing is, it is reading my /public folder because when I go to laravel.dev it redirects me to laravel.dev/home, which it's supposed to do.

I have adjusted my database.php file to match my Windows configuration, and I made sure my vhost file had the same arguments as they did on Ubuntu.  I know my configuration is correct because if I create a new project with composer, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to setup a .htaccess in your root directory.

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```